# Node.js get a computer network ip format usable in an external LAN post request

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below is built to fetch the network ip of a computer in a LAN network.

I need to identify the computer's network ip format like '192.1.xx.x.x59' that can be usable when making an external LAN post request.

The problem is the code keeps returning '0.0.0.0' as the network ip.

Could you please help me spot the problem with this code.

Thanks in advance!

```js
function getIPAddress() {
    var interfaces = require('os').networkInterfaces();
    for (var devName in interfaces) {
      var iface = interfaces[devName];
  
      for (var i = 0; i < iface.length; i++) {
        var alias = iface[i];
        if (alias.family === 'IPv4' && alias.address !== '127.0.0.1' && !alias.internal)
          return alias.address;
      }
    }
    return '0.0.0.0';
}

console.log(getIPAddress());
```

Comment: Try inserting some additional self-debugging info into your code, such as console.log's inside your loop there, that apparently is never passing the condition you have in there with all those `&&`s.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you start this code in your debugger, step line by line through the code, and add some debugging details to your question? Does the code flow enter the outer loop? Does it enter the inner loop? What is `interfaces`? What is `iface.length`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your code, I think you didn't connect to any network wifi or something. So, returning 0.0.0.0

you can see by logging `interfaces`

```js
var interfaces = require('os').networkInterfaces();

console.log(interfaces);
```

Comment: OP's code shows that it will return "0.0.0.0" by this statement `return '0.0.0.0';` when the loop itself never returns via the `if` statement. But I didn't downvote you.